# Custom multi-select and single select issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i have created a component which works perfect apart from binding the a string rather than an array. The event's fire correctly.

So on the multi-select version if I select and deselect items the `multiSelected` variable is updated correctly. However when selecting another value within the single select the `singleSelected` variable isn't being changed, however the same event is firing.

Dummed down the code here so you can just see the logic and issue:

```js
Vue.component('dropdown', {
  template: `<div class="dropdown">
    <label v-for="item in items" :key="item.value" :class="{selected:selected.indexOf(item.value) > -1}">
      {{ item.label }}
      <input type="checkbox" :value="item.value" :checked="selected.indexOf(item.value) > -1" @change="selected = $event" />
    </label>
  </div>`,
  props: [ 'value', 'items', 'multiSelect' ],
  computed: {
    selected: {
      get: function() {
        if (this.value === undefined) {
          return [];
        }
        if (!Array.isArray(this.value)) {
          return [ this.value ];
        }
        return this.value;
      },
      set: function($event) {
        let current = this.selected;

        if (!this.multiSelect) {
          current = $event.target.value;
        }

        if (this.multiSelect && !$event.target.checked) {
          const index = current.indexOf($event.target.value);
          if (index > -1) {
            current.splice(index, 1)
          }
        }
        if (this.multiSelect && $event.target.checked) {
          current.push($event.target.value);
        }

        console.log(current);
        this.$emit('value', current);
      }
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('wrapper', {
  template: `
    <div>
      Single
      <dropdown :items="items" v-model="singleSelected" :multi-select="false" name="single" />
      <br />
      Multi
      <dropdown :items="items" v-model="multiSelected" :multi-select="true" name="multi" />
      <p>Models</p>
      <p>singleSelected: {{ singleSelected }}</p>
      <p>multiSelected: {{ multiSelected }}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{value:'bmw',label:'BMW',count:1},{value:'audi',label:'Audi',count:1},{value:'kia',label:'KIA',count:1}],
      multiSelected: ['kia'],
      singleSelected: 'kia',
    }
  }
});

new Vue().$mount('#app');
```

```css
.dropdown {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
label {
  margin: 5px;
}


.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <wrapper>
    
  </wrapper>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use an array - `current = [$event.target.value];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`v-model` on custom component [expects](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) that the component will emit `input` event, not `value`

Only reason why your component is (sort of) working in multi-select mode is because you are directly mutating the input array passed to you by a `value` prop (in other words the emitted event is useless). Don't do that. Create a new array instead before emitting

Also, there is one more issue with single-select mode - after deselecting only checked box, you still emitting the value so the model is set to a value even none of the checkboxes is checked

Personally I find your design strange for several reasons:

1. Using different `v-model` "type" (array or string) feels unnatural
2. In single-select mode it behaves as radio so why not use radio
3. What will happen if you switch `multiSelect` prop at runtime?

```js
Vue.component('dropdown', {
  template: `<div class="dropdown">
    <label v-for="item in items" :key="item.value" :class="{selected:selected.indexOf(item.value) > -1}">
      {{ item.label }}
      <input type="checkbox" :value="item.value" :checked="selected.indexOf(item.value) > -1" @change="selected = $event" />
    </label>
  </div>`,
  props: [ 'value', 'items', 'multiSelect' ],
  computed: {
    selected: {
      get: function() {
        if (this.value === undefined) {
          return [];
        }
        if (!Array.isArray(this.value)) {
          return [ this.value ];
        }
        return this.value;
      },
      set: function($event) {
        if(this.multiSelect) {
          if (!$event.target.checked) {
            this.$emit('input', this.selected.filter(v => v !== $event.target.value))
          } else {
            this.$emit('input', [...this.selected, $event.target.value])
          }
        } else {
          this.$emit('input', $event.target.checked ? $event.target.value : "")
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('wrapper', {
  template: `
    <div>
      Single
      <dropdown :items="items" v-model="singleSelected" :multi-select="false" name="single" />
      <br />
      Multi
      <dropdown :items="items" v-model="multiSelected" :multi-select="true" name="multi" />
      <p>Models</p>
      <p>singleSelected: {{ singleSelected }}</p>
      <p>multiSelected: {{ multiSelected }}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{value:'bmw',label:'BMW',count:1},{value:'audi',label:'Audi',count:1},{value:'kia',label:'KIA',count:1}],
      multiSelected: ['kia'],
      singleSelected: 'kia',
    }
  }
});

new Vue().$mount('#app');
```

```css
.dropdown {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
label {
  margin: 5px;
}


.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <wrapper>
    
  </wrapper>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a silly mistake on my part, I should have double checked the event I was emitting.